# Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord Single Table Inheritance has_one to superclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, polymorphism, single-table-inheritance

I have a `Base` class which contains STI and named `procedures`, looking like this:

```rb
class Base < ActiveRecord
  self.abstract_class = true
  self.table_name = "procedures"
  self.inheritance_column = nil
end
```

We also have multiple superclasses named for isntance `ProcedureA` and `ProcedureB`, looking like this:

```rb
class ProcedureA < Base
end

class ProcedureB < Base
end
```

A procedure can contain another procedure so i'd like to add this to the base class. But when retrieving the other procedure i'd like to know the actual class name. So this works:

```rb
class Base < ActiveRecord
  self.abstract_class = true
  self.table_name = "procedures"
  self.inheritance_column = nil

  has_one :parent, class_name: "Base"
end
```

But when retrieving it form the database it returns is as the `Base` class but not the specific class that was assigned.

For instance:

```rb
procedure_a = ProcedureA.create!()
procedure_b = ProcedureB.create!()
procedure_a.parent = procedure_b
procedure_a.save!

procedure_a.parent => Is ProcedureB
ProcedureA.first.parent => Is Base class
```

So at this point i don't know how to get the actual class instead of the base class. I tried playing with `polymorphic: true` but doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of confusion going on here.

To create a [self referential assocation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins) you need to use `belongs_to` not `has_one`.

```ruby
class User
  belongs_to :manager, 
    class_name: 'User',
    optional: true
  has_many :subordinates,
    class_name: 'User',
    foreign_key: :manager_id
end
```

After all the foreign key is [stored on *this* models table](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs-to-and-has-one).

But then there is also the fact that your Base is actively sabotaging Single Table Inheritance. It should just read:

```
class Base < ActiveRecord
  self.table_name = "procedures" # all children will be stored in this table
end
```

`self.abstract_class = true` tells ActiveRecord to ignore this class when resolving the table name of its children. That's the opposite of what you want.

`self.inheritance_column = nil` disables the type inferance that you need for single table inheritance to work.

The way STI in Rails works you don't actually have to do anything. Any class that inherits from ActiveRecord::Base and is not abstract is a STI parent class by default. All you need to do is add a `type` column and subclasses and bob's your uncle.

Adding the self-referential assocation with STI is pretty much the same as above example but with a twist:

```
class Base < ActiveRecord
  belongs_to :parent,
    class_name: 'Base',
    optional: true
end
```

`class_name: 'Base',` seems kind of odd but its really just telling Rails which table to look for the assocatiated records on. When loading the record the type inferance will override what class is instanciated anyways (or at least it would if you didn't sabotage it).

Note that this is not a case where you want a polymorphic assocation. Thats used when you have a single assocation that points to multiple different tables.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your explanation is understandable and clear! I'm relative new to ruby and used to C#, so i'm still figuring out this kind of stuff.

Comment: Its quite understandable to be confused. The Rails STI implementation is downright weird in that its enabled by default and `self.abstract_class` is a horrible naming decision as it has a bunch of effects that you would not expect.